# Rails: redirection problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I don't want people to be able to go to /cvit so I had it redirected like so in routes.rb

```
match '/cvit' => redirect("/cvit/new")
```

but this causes a problem because you cannot get to /cvit/51 (a results page) because it would also redirect that to /cvit/new. How can I get around this??? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have done:

```
resources :cvits, :path => 'cvit' do
  get 'new' , :on => :collection
end
```

Answer (score 1):

mmmmm I thought it should work fine. Then try this:

```
match '/:cvit' => redirect("/cvit/new"), :constraints => { :cvit => "cvit" }
```